# Can I release an object after autorelease in Objective-C 2.0

Tags: objective-c

My development environment:

> Xcode 4.6.2
>
> non-Automatic Reference Counting

For example, suppose we have a view controller called `CertainViewController.m`, where a property called `certainProperty` with attributes `retain` and `nonatomic` is declared.

```
// CertainViewController.h
@interface CertainViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) certainPropertyClass *listData;

// CertainViewController.m
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.certainProperty = [[[certainPropertyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    // Among other initialization...
}
```

In the `dealloc` method, there is implicit `release` when we assign a new value to the the property `certainProperty`. Not sure this is potentially hazardous or not.

```
// CertainViewController.m
- (void) dealloc
{
    self.certainProperty = nil;
}
```

Please share some insight, thank you :D

Comment: `[[[self.certainProperty alloc] init] autorelease];` is kinda nonsense.

Comment: Oops, did it quick then made such a silly mistake :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not strictly hazardous to release a variable with `autorelease` in a non-ARC environment. However, it's not considered great practice to just tag on `autorelease` to variables that you could manually release just as easily. `autorelease` is really meant to be used when you want to get rid of an object as soon as the system no longer needs it, usually at a time you won't know. So while your code isn't strictly invalid, just know that it's best to manually call `release` when you know exactly when to release an object, such as in your `-dealloc` method.

Answer (score 3):

First, you code is wrong

```
// CertainViewController.m
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //[[[self.certainProperty alloc] init] autorelease]; // this is a nop if self.certainProperty is nil or crash if not nil
    self.certainProperty = [[[YourPropertyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    // Among other initialization...
}


// CertainViewController.m
- (void) dealloc
{
    self.certainProperty = nil;
    [super dealloc]; // you must call super
}
```

Second, assuming `certainProperty` is a retained property, assign a value to it will call `retain` by the setter.

So doing

```
self.certainProperty = nil;
```

in `dealloc` is required to balance the retain count otherwise `certainProperty` will be leaked.

Comment: Unless `yourProperty` is of type `Class`, which complicates things.

Comment: @xlc any detail about how does `dealloc` do the balance of retain count? Thumb up for your correction :D

Comment: @congliu you need to release every ivar in `dealloc`. thats the rule

Answer (score 1):

If you put it in the autorelease pool then you should let autorelease take care of it. Personally, I would handle the releasing of the object myself unless it requires an autorelease pool (say, some GUI object reference). But setting it to `nil` is not a problem. You can perform operations all day long on a `nil` object with no side effects.

Comment: Any detail on your GUI object reference? Nice explanation :D

Comment: It's been a while since I've done any OSX/iOS development. So I don't have a concrete example off the top of my head. But there will be times where it is clear that you should let the runtime handle the memory for your object. That's all that reference was meant to allude to.

Answer (score 1):

**Stick to the convention. Don't defy the usual memory model unless there's something really important that can't be done otherwise.**

`release` decreases the retain count by 1. So it's not safe to call `release` for it. One other object may have retained this, so the retain count is 1. So calling `release` may cause it to be deallocated. **That's in general.**

If you have a `retain` property, then assigning an object to it will result in retaining that object.

`self.retainProperty = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease]`
 Will result in retainCount = 1.

**Note:** The way you initialize `certainProperty` in `viewDidLoad:` is wrong. `alloc` is a class method, it actually returns a new allocated object. So `[[[self.certainProperty alloc] init] autorelease];` Will not set your property. Do as xlc said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16726621/959221).